# Remove the forbidden "view more (votes)" link on user profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed

When you visit your profile, below the **Votes Cast**, there is a `view more` link which takes you to:

```
https://superuser.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=votes
```

---

[image: iglvzx]
 https://superuser.com/users/100787/iglvzx?tab=votes

---

### Surprisingly,

this link also appears on other users' profiles. Fortunately, Good Guy Stack Exchange gives you a **Page Not Found** error. *(Which can be interpreted as **HTTP 403 Forbidden**)*

---

[image: studiohack]
 https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack?tab=votes

---

Can we remove this link when we visit **other** users' profiles?

Comment: That's a network wide issue: [“View more” Votes profile button link broken? - Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134108/view-more-votes-profile-button-link-broken)

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "view more" link will no longer be shown if you're not viewing your own profile.